# Get input from dialog edittext and display in listview

Tags: android

User clicks the floating action button the dialogBox opens. Get the input from the user(eg: title and count value user can enter in the editText of the dialogBox)If the user clicks "Ok" the entered data must be stored in listView which is created in `res/layout/list_view.xml` I created a dialogBox using the JAVA code.

```
 public void openDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder mydialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddCount.this);
      mydialog.setTitle("Add Count");
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(AddCount.this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText title = new EditText(AddCount.this);
    title.setHint("Title");
    layout.addView(title);

    final EditText value = new EditText(AddCount.this);
    value.setHint("Count");
    layout.addView(value);

    mydialog.setView(layout);


  mydialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

          Toast.makeText(AddCount.this,"Saved ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
  });

  mydialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
          dialogInterface.cancel();
      }
  });
  mydialog.show();
}
```

How to store and display the data  in listview which is entered in dialogbox by the user. And is it possible to use sharedpreference? so that the data can't be lose until the user delete it. Help me to slove this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for that. On positiveButtonClick append that item to a list and update your RecylcerView with that. And for saving the data you can use SharedPreferences but [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) is a better option.